# How do I make an SQLITE database programatically in Qt?

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt4

I am making a contact book application in Qt.
I want my application to automatically create an QSQLITE database when it first runs and then access this database in future?
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qsqlite please read the docs and try things out.

Comment: @W.K.S a upwote frm me. :) if i see eny question is downvoted i will defenetly give a upvote for it. because enyone have the write to ask enything he/she dosnt know.

Comment: @Lakshan : my thought exactly! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya you can create sqlite database at its first run and can make it progressive. Just do it in the constructor of your App and check for the existence of db before cerating it, else don't create. You can access database in subsequent runs of your same App or different App.

Use `db.setDatabaseName("databasename.db");` instead of `db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");`, now your database will be `persistent`.

Comment: Could you please give some example code? I've tried numerous ways but I just can't get it to work?

Comment: Are you using QtCreator? If so it has examples that uses sqlite database.

Comment: Yes I did. In the Cached Table example, a database is made in memory and contacts are added to it programatically each time the program is run. I don't want that. I want to make a progressive database.